Integration with cylindrical coordinates to compute volume
I have to calculate the volume between $x^2+y^2+z^2\le2$, $x^2+y^2\le z^2$ and $z\ge0$ using cylindrical coordinates.
From first equation I get $r^2+z^2\le2$ and from second one  $r^2\le z^2$. I get stuck at setting the boundaries: I set them as
$$\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^\sqrt{2} dr \int_r^\sqrt{2-r^2}rdz,$$
but the result is $0$. Where did I make mistake?

But have you a simple triple integral $\iiint_T dxdydz$ where $T$ is your domain?

From an abstract standpoint, zero volume makes sense. The intersection you describe, of being inside a sphere of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and above the plane $z=2$, is precisely empty, and thus has no volume.

Sorry, it was $z \ge 0$, my mistake.

You initially misidentified the boundary for the variable $r$. It is crucial to ensure that the boundary inequality
$$r\leq z \leq\sqrt{2-r^2}$$
must always exist a valid $z$ for all $r$ within the integrated region. To determine the upper limit of $r$, you need to solve this equation
$$r=\sqrt{2-r^2}$$
which yields $r=1$. Now, finding the volume $V$ of the region:
$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta\int_0^{1}\mathrm{d}r\int_r^{\sqrt{2-r^2}}r\;\mathrm{d}z=\frac{4\pi\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)}{3}.$$

HINT:
See if the yz section

is of some help. On full $ \theta = 2 \pi $ rotation around z axis  you have a spherical cap and a cone of apex angle $90^{\circ}.$
